# How to move Stage in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

How to move Stage?

I am looking for an example:

```
stage.draw(x,y); // ???
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not move the stage, you should move the viewport for the stage.

You need to make sure when you call this

```
stage.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
```

that the last parameter is false, so that the viewport is not always centered.
You can then set

```
stage.getViewport().getCamera().position.x
```

or call

```
stage.getViewport().getCamera().translate()
```

before calling

```
stage.getViewport().getCamera().update()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to move all sprites on Stage, use root

My example (I use stages as windows and make transitions for window changes)

```
 private void startShowTransition(Stage stage) {
    stage.getRoot().setX(WINDOW_START_X);
    stage.getRoot().setY(WINDOW_START_Y);

    stage.addAction(Actions.moveTo(WINDOW_FINAL_X,
            WINDOW_FINAL_Y,
            WINDOW_TRANSITION_DURATION));
}
```

And note - you can use Actions for smooth stage changes effects!